# How to send Drozone.js data to Symfony server

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js to upload multiple files with a dropzone and an image preview, which works well, and this file field is part of a form with other fields from Symfony formBuilder.

What I would like now is to be able to send those file data to my Symfony server side.
I followed [this tutorial](https://digitalfortress.tech/js/js-file-upload-dropzone-symfony/), but the part where he gets the data returns null for me: `$request->files->get('file')` (of course by changing 'file' with 'product_form[distilleryPhotos][]' for me).

Moreover, my distilleryPhotos field from the builder isn't replaced by the Dropzone one. They seem to be two different fields on front side.

Here is my Controller function:

```
#[Route('/products/{id}', name: 'product_details', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function show(int $id, Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator, SluggerInterface $slugger): Response
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class);

    $product = $repository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

    $form = $this->createForm(ProductFormType::class, $product, ['attr' =>
        [
            'class' => 'dropzone',
            'id'    => 'distillery-photos-dropzone'
        ]
    ]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $product->setName($form->get('name')->getData());
        $product->setAge($form->get('age')->getData());
        $distilleryPhotos = $form->get('distilleryPhotos')->getData();

        if($distilleryPhotos)
        {
            $photos = [];
            foreach($distilleryPhotos as $distilleryPhoto)
            {
                $originalFilename = pathinfo($distilleryPhoto->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                // this is needed to safely include the file name as part of the URL
                $safeFilename = $slugger->slug($originalFilename);
                $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$distilleryPhoto->guessExtension();

                // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
                try
                {
                    $distilleryPhoto->move(
                        $this->getParameter('distillery_photos_directory'),
                        $newFilename
                    );
                }
                catch (FileException $e)
                {
                    throwException($e);
                }

                $photos[] = $newFilename;

                // updates the 'brochureFilename' property to store the PDF file name
                // instead of its contents
            }
            $product->setDistilleryPhotos($photos);
        }

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($product);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', $translator->trans('Your product was updated successfully.'));

        return $this->redirectToRoute('product_details', [
            'id' => $id,
        ]);
    }
```

My twig:

```
        <form name="product_form" method="post" class="dropzone" id="distillery-photos-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ path('product_details', {'id': product.id}) }}">
    {{ form_end(productForm) }}
```

And my JS:

```
let fileUploadActionName = document.querySelector('#distillery-photos-dropzone').action;

let distilleryPhotosDropzone = new Dropzone(
    "#distillery-photos-dropzone",
    {
        paramName: "product_form[distilleryPhotos][]",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        maxFile: 10,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        init: function () {
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
                this.removeFile(file);
            });
            this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
                // send additional data with the file as POST data if needed.
                // formData.append("key", "value");
            });
            this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                if (response.uploaded)
                    alert('File Uploaded: ' + response.fileName);
            });
        }
    }
);

distilleryPhotosDropzone.on("addedfile", file => {
    console.log(`File added: ${file.name}`);
});
```

Comment: For Dropzone, You can send your files through ajax request, your ajax 'url' param is missing, you can keep the files in the session as hold ( if requires ), and if you want to send any some other data send it separately and process it together ( if u wish )

Comment: Oh that's a great idea! I didn't think about using the session. However, after the form submit, when I try to get the data I stored in session in JS with $request->getSession(), it doesn't retrieve it... Although I can see the data in session in the browser. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful for new visitors. You can use a library that extends Symfony Form and adds a new type [DropzneType](https://github.com/emr-dev/symfony-dropzone).

Example

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface 
    $builder, array $options){ 
        // userFiles is OneToMany
        $builder->add('userFiles', DropzoneType::class, [
            'class' => File::class,
            'maxFiles' => 6,
            'uploadHandler'=>'uploadhandler',  // route name
            'removeHandler'=> 'removeHandler'// route name
       ]);
    }
```